# über das Verb "beißen"

Tags: grammar, verb

Wenn ich richtig verstanden habe, ist das Verb "beißen" ein Verb mit Akk.-Ergänzung und es ist auch ein teilreflexives Verb mit reflexiven Pronomen im Akkusativ; wenn alles korrekt ist, warum habe ich [hier](http://dict.leo.org/itde/index_de.html#/search=mordere&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) die folgende Beispiele?

[image]

Comment: Lexika erfassen nicht immer alle möglichen Verbkonstruktionen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Dativ-Komplement kann zu sehr vielen Verben dazutreten, ohne daß es die eigentliche Verb-Valenz erfüllt, besonders als Reflexivpronomen. Manchmal ist die selbstbezügliche Bedeutung derart offensichtlich, daß sie in anderen Sprachen gar nicht ausgedrückt wird:

> Sie biß sich auf die Lippen == She bit her lip

Manchmal ist sie optional:

> Ich kaufe mir einen Laptop == I'm buying (myself) a laptop

Wenn der Bezug obligatorisch ist und die Bedeutung grundlegend beeinflußt, kann man den Dativ eher als Teil der Verb-Valenz ansehen:

> Ich vertraue dir == I trust you

Der Fachbegriff fūr Deine Beispiele ist *ethischer Dativ*, und er kann verwirrend wirken, weil es ja auch echte Dativ-Objekte gibt, also eben nicht jeder Dativ ein ethischer Dativ ist (auch wenn bei vielen echten Valenzen eine enge semantische Verwandtschaft besteht).

Comment: Ist das wirklich der ethische Dativ? Imho ist es der 'richtige' Dativ. "Wem beiße ich auf die Lippen? -> Ich beiße ihm auf die Lippen". Das Verb "beißen" hat entw. ein Akk-Objekt ("jdn beißen") oder Dat-Objekt + Präp.-Phrase: ("jdm auf etw. beißen" - "jdm in den Augen beißen"). Beispiele für den ethischen Dativ wären: Dass du mir keinen Ärger machst, Cry me a river. Der Kern diesen Dativs ist ja die "emotionale Anteilnahme". Beim sich auf die Lippen beißen, liegt das nicht vor; auch wenn's weh tut.

Comment: @Em1 Wenn's nicht der ethische Dativ ist, so ist es zumindest ein relativ frei eintretendes Dativkonstrukt mit ähnlicher Semantik, das zu so vielen Verben treten kann, daß es nicht sinnvoll ist, es überall als "optionalen Dativ" dazuzubeschreiben. In Wirklichkeit sind all diese Dativvarianten eigentlich Punkte auf einem Kontinuum, aber Grammatik braucht eben feste Kategorien, um Dinge anständig beschreiben zu können (oder glaubt das jedenfalls).

Comment: Interessant wäre hier, das mal mit den romanischen Sprachen zu vergleichen. Und laut dict.leo heißt es z.B. im Spanischen "morderse la lengua". Der Vergleich mit dem Englischen hinkt insofern, dass das Englische sehr sparsam mit solchen Konstrukten ist. "Cry me a river" ist schon wirklich eine Ausnahme. "She bit her lip" ist die Regel. Daher sehe ich den Vergleich mit Englisch hier unangebracht. (Falls c.p. über diesen Kommentar stolpert, mag er vielleicht seinen Senf dazu geben, wie's im Spanischen wirklich aussieht!?)

Comment: @Em1 Stimmt. Wie du richtig schreibst, sagt man *morder**se** la lengua*. Das scheint nicht der ethische Dativ zu sein. Im Spanischen sind aber  Beispiele sowohl echter Dativi als auch dieser Dativi ethici reichlich vorhanden. Etwa: (aus dem deutschen Beispiel auf canoo.net) "komm mir nicht zu spät" wäre auch genau so auf Spanisch "¡(Y) no *me* llegues muy tarde!". Und Spanisch aus der Halbinsel nutzt noch viel mehr solche Reflexive. Vielleicht schreibe ich eine Antwort später.

Answer (score 2):

Ja, das Verb *beißen* hat in aller Regel ein Akkusativobjekt, das ausdrückt, *wen oder was* gebissen wird. (Es gibt auch das intransitive Verb *beißen*, das aber nicht Gegenstand dieser Frage ist.)

> Der Hund beißt den Mann.
>
> Den Hund beißt der Mann.

Oder aber reflexiv:

> Der Hund biss sich.
>
> Ich beiße mich.

Hier hören aber schon die einfachen Fälle auf, und mit jeder weiteren Präzisierung wird es komplex. Ich könnte zum Beispiel meine Zähne in ein Hähnchenschenkel schlagen, dann gilt:

> Ich beiße *in* den Schenkel.

Obwohl es so aussieht wie vorher. Wenn ich mit meinen Zähnen aber nicht in das Fleisch eindringen kann, weil es so zäh ist, oder weil ich den Knochen direkt erwische:

> Ich beiße *auf* den Schenkel.

Immerhin steht das, was gebissen wird, noch im Akkusativ. Wir könnten aber genauer werden, und aufführen in *wessen* Bein gebissen wird.

> Der Hund beißt *den Mann ins Bein*

wäre, so gesehen, erst einmal korrekt. Das Deutsche hat allerdings die Tendenz, doppelte Akkusative zu vermeiden. Deswegen wird man mindestens gleich oft folgende Variante hören:

> Der Hund beißt *de**m** Mann ins Bein*.

Insbesondere die festen Wendungen *sich auf die Zunge beißen* und *sich auf die Lippen beißen* sind so verbreitet, dass die Person, die gebissen wird, bloß noch im Dativ ausgedrückt wird.

> Ich beiße mir auf die Zunge.